# Nodejs giving 404 error on hosting in cpanel?

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I tried to run Nodejs app on cPanel. I saw YouTube tutorial and in YouTube everyone is running fine with hello world message, but when I apply same step( step as below), I get 404 error? where am I missing?

steps I followed

1. I went to cPanel and to Nodejs setup
2. I filled up empty spaces as below screenshots.
3. and when I click the link i am getting 404 error.

do I also need to add .htaccess file?
also I tried package.json file.

[image]